# How to get double click on xamDataGrid using QTP/UFT?

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, xamdatagrid

How to get double click on xamDataGrid row to open a window using QTP

I have searched stackoverflow But not getting anything for QTP or UFT. I have tried double click row and fireevent but no use.

Is it possible by doing in QTP?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Object.XamDataGrid(strobject).ActivateRecord i   
Object.XamDataGrid(strobject).Select gridRecord,i
Call Object.XamDataGrid(strobject).DblClick(1,1)
```

After Selecting row if you double click it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using DeviceReplay,

```
Function DbClick(traget)
    Set DeviceReplay = CreateObject ("Mercury.DeviceReplay")
    abs_x = traget1.GetROProperty("abs_x")
    abs_y = traget1.GetROProperty("abs_y")

    DeviceReplay.MouseMove abs_x, abs_y
    DeviceReplay.MouseDblClick abs_x, abs_y, 0
    Set DeviceReplay = Nothing
End Function
```

traget would be the object which you would like to double click

Comment: Its a grid,so full grid is an object. If I take abs_x, abs_y it wont helpful. Thanks for your comment. I found the solution.

Comment: it would be helpful for others if you share the solution also